# filterContentForSearch - with Dictionaries

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, dictionary

I have a question, I do have an array which holds dictionaries, these dictionaries then go into a tableView. Now I need a search Function to filter the Table.

For example: I have that kind of `Array/Dictionary`

```
var filteredItems = [[String: String]]()
var unfilteredItems = [[String: String]]()
```

and then I wanted to filter that with a function like this

```
func filterContentForSearch (searchText:String, scope: Int) {
        self.filteredItems = self.unfilteredItems.filter({ (description: String) -> Bool in
            var searchMatch = description.rangeOfString(searchText)
            return searchMatch != nil
        })

    }
```

My feeling says there is something wrong and it don't work, so far I couldn't figure out what could be the issue or an approach which could work... any ideas?

The error message I get from Xcode is: "`[String, String]` is not a subtype of String

Running on Xcode 6.1.1

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did it:

```
func filterContentForSearch (searchText:String, scope: Int) {
    self.unfiltredItems = filtredItems.filter({
        $0["description"] == searchText 

    })
}
```

Very simple but it works...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var filteredItems : NSArray = [];
var unfilteredItems : NSArray = []; // this array should contain your string data

    func filterContentForSearch (searchText:String, scope: Int) {
       if let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS %@", searchText) {
          self.filteredItems = self.unfilteredItems.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
       }
       else 
          self.filteredItems = nil;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but that don't work, it tells me that String don't have a member called "filteredArrayUsingPredicate"

Comment: Oh sorry its a method in NSArray class, required to change variable declaration

Comment: what was the solution?

Comment: See below my solution

Answer (score 0):

You have dictionaries in unfilteredItems array. But you treat them as String inside filter closure. Correct type should be

```
(description: [String: String]) -> Bool
```